# REST-WebService that takes csv which itself gets modified with SpringBatch

Tags: web-services, csv, spring-batch

My task is to write a REST WebService that can take a csv. This csv should then be modified via SpringBatch. I either worked with WebServices nor did i work with SpringBatch.
Can you give me a short intro of how to achieve my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Short example on rest webservice you can find [here](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/7-Simple-REST-Web-Service-in-Java-with-Spring-and-CXF.html)
2. You can get spring batch exampe [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-batch-tutorial/). You can use merge example 2 and example 4 of itemreader and itemwriter and itemprocessor.
3. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248910/how-to-trigger-a-job-using-a-rest-web-service/20261602#20261602) to call spring batch from rest service layer